# error in android studio in which resource values directory show error

Tags: android, android-resources

```
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"Invalid resource directory name","sources":[{"file":"C:\\Users\\dell\\AndroiedStudioProjects\\Universal3\\app\\src\\main\\res\\values-hindi"}],"tool":"Resource and asset merger"}
```

In which values hindi file are deleted but its show error

[Screenshot of error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DWqNg.png)

i am adding hindi language option in app but is not work then i am deleting valued hindi option and its deleted and not showing in values option but its show error when app is running